# Landscape width ads with admob and android

Tags: android, admob

Is there a way to get landscape ads with admob? I've got my ads appearing landscape but they are only about half the width of the screen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is the normal behavior because the ads for phones have a **fixed** size no matter the orientation of the phone, see [this link](http://code.google.com/mobile/ads/docs/android/intermediate.html) for more information. On a tablet on the other hand you have more options for ads size. 
So there isn't much to do , just work with the fixed size you are given and cover the empty space you might get from ads not filling the phone width in landscape mode(if you designed the layout in this way).

Answer (score 1):

I realise it is an old question but now it is possible to achieve what the OP had asked for. *Smart Banners* are available, just set the value for your `adSize` as `SMART_BANNER`.

```
ads:adSize="SMART_BANNER"
```

[Documentation Reference](https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/docs/admob/smart-banners)